# Complex use of substrings in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a block of XML code that implements attributes about a family:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<family>
    <familySurname>Smith</familySurname>
        <biography firstName="John">
            <family position="dad">1</family>
            <family information="name">Smith_John (123)</family>
        </biography>
        <biography firstName="Jane">
            <family position="mom">2</family>
            <family information="name">Smith_Jane (456)</family>
        </biography>
        <biography firstName="Kelsey">
            <family position="daughter">3</family>
            <family information="name">Smith_Kelsey (789)</family>
        </biography>
</family>
```

I'm hoping to write an XSL code that will output the following:

```
Smith 123 John
Smith 456 Jane
Smith 789 Kelsey
```

I have the fixed-width bit down (have written a function for that), so I'm good to go there. However, I am getting hung up on how keep the familySurname element constant, while running through and sub-stringing each of the family @information attributes.

Would somebody be able to help me logically process this in XSL? I'm brand new to the language.

Comment: Please explain the logic by which you arrive at the output shown. There is no "John" in the `@information` attribute.

Comment: Thanks zx, I corrected it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Michael.hor - I had a typo in the code (using sample data), didn't change Bob to John!

Comment: Does you processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Thanks for your formatting help. Should be good to go, I think.

Comment: I think we need to keep it 1.0 for now

Comment: Where does fixed width come into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these three templates. The first one skips the `familySurname` output, the second one just passes on from the `family` elements and the third one formats the output.

```
<xsl:template match="familySurname" />

<xsl:template match="family">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="biography">
    <xsl:variable name="str"       select="family[@information='name']" />
    <xsl:variable name="lastName"  select="substring-before($str,'_')" />
    <xsl:variable name="firstName" select="substring-before(substring-after($str,'_'),' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="index"     select="substring-before(substring-after($str,'('),')')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($lastName,' ',$index,' ',$firstName)" />
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
Smith 123 John
Smith 456 Jane
Smith 789 Kelsey
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you both so much for your help. Took me a while to troubleshoot it in different specifics, but consider this officially answered. Thanks for taking the time to go over this with me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to be "running through and sub-stringing each of the family @information attributes", when you can extract all of them, except the one in parentheses, from their proper places:

```
<xsl:template match="family">
    <xsl:variable name="surname" select="familySurname" />
    <xsl:for-each select="biography">
        <xsl:value-of select="$surname"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(family[@information='name'], '('), ')') "/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@firstName"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```